# Sharing a single .editorconfig file across multiple projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, editorconfig

My team maintains several Java repositories in GitHub. Each of them has an .editorconfig file in the root folder and they're all exactly the same. This makes maintaining them a bit of a pain because they all have to be updated individually.

All of us use IntelliJ, which has a feature that will download checkstyle rules from a URL, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that with the .editorconfig rules.

All of our projects use Maven. Is there any way to make the .editorconfig file accessible through an API and have the projects configured to automatically download it and put it in the root folder?

For anyone not familiar with EditorConfig, more info is [here](http://editorconfig.org/).

Comment: For those like me unfamiliar with what this does, could you explain as well as tell what this solves?

Comment: It's a plugin and config file supported by multiple editors and IDEs that helps to maintain a consistent code style.

Comment: Is the .editorconfig file the same for all projects?  If so just ask each developer to have a copy in $HOME (or the root of each drive)

Answer (score 2):

I made a tool to solve this kind of problem. It is developed as an NPM package but it is basically just a command line tool so it should work for this case. If you execute something like `npx your-dictator-name@version` with [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

The tool is called [Dictator Builder](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-builder) and helps create "dictators". A dictator is the command line tool that contains "dictatables", your `.editorconfig` can be part of a "dictatable".

In your case you could have a `.dictatable-config.json` with something like:

```
{
  "message": "Copy editorconfig",
  "actions": [
    {
      "copyFrom": ".editorconfig",
      "target": "."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and I have been solving this by using `hardlinks` via `mklink /h`. So far I have not had any issues with it as with some users having issues with `softlinks` ([.editorconfig in shared Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186841/editorconfig-in-shared-git-repository)) I am not clear what the issue with the softlink is.

Answer (score -2):

Quoting that same [EditorConfig docs](https://editorconfig.org/#file-location) you mentioned:

> When opening a file, EditorConfig plugins look for a file named `.editorconfig` in the directory of the opened file and in every parent directory. A search for `.editorconfig` files will stop if the root filepath is reached or an EditorConfig file with `root=true` is found.

Therefore the most convenient and easy-to-manage approach is to make a single `.editorconfig` file and place it somewhere at the parent dir of all your repositories. That file has to have the `root=true` line in it.

This can perhaps be further improved by storing the file in *one* repository and making a *symlink* to it in the parent dir:

```
cd <parent_dir_for_all_repos>
ln -s .../path/to/.editorconfig
```

Comment: I think that this might have been downvoted since OP wants to commit the .editorConfig file with the repo and your solution does not address this. Still I think that it might be a good solution.