# .editorConfig in multiple projects with hardlinks

Tags: editorconfig, hardlink

I have a similar scenario as those described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186841/editorconfig-in-shared-git-repository) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566027/sharing-a-single-editorconfig-file-across-multiple-projects): I want to have a single `.editorConfig` file, but be able to commit it to multiple repos (one to many). I have read that there are some issues with creating `softlinks` and `symlinks` on git, but I have not found much about `hardlinks`.

My questions:

- Is this discouraged somehow? I understand that specific projects might have specific `editorConfig` requirements. Also, that changing one of the files will generate a git change in multiple repos, but this does not bother me, since I pretend the style to be consistent across my repos (I work mainly with `c#`).
- Will it behave differently in different environments with git (linux, osx, windows)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation too. I have a repository that contains the `.editorconfig` file. This repo is a single source of truth for coding guideline. I also have several (approximately 40) code repositories written by C#.

For local environment:

- I always clone repositories to a specific folder. If this is related to my job, it goes into the `work` folder; or if this is my personal project, it goes into the `personal` folder, etc. I copy the `.editorconfig` file from the guideline repository to the same level as my repository folder. Thus, whole repositories can use a single/same `.editorconfig` file. I also have a specific `.editorconfig` file in the `personal` folder. So, I can override some repository rules like this. Maybe you do not like my copying approach, but I do not think these rules are changed often.

For continuous integration:

- I never trust developers. They can ignore the error/warnings or they don't use IDE. For this case, I added a new task to my CI pipeline before the build step. This task clones the coding guideline repository and copies the `.editorconfig` file to the build directory. In this way, `dotnet build` command finds the `.editorconfig` file and uses it.

I know this is not a solid solution to your question but I wanted to give an idea.